# 400W inverter not charging power tool battery charger

Tags: inverter, circuit-protection

I have a 2018 Ford SuperDuty with a factory 400 Watt AC inverter. When I plug in a Milwaukee charger, the circuit protection light starts flashing and the battery will not charge. The charger does not give a wattage rating, but states that the input should 120V at 2.1amps. This should be 252 Watts required by the charger. I have plugged the charger into a Kill-A-Watt device and it only shows 0.8 Watts with a fully charged battery on the charger and 73 Watts when a discharged battery is installed. Why would the circuit protection light start flashing when everything I'm seeing is showing that the charger is pulling far less power than the inverter is rated for? I suspect that it has something to do with the type of inverter. I suspect that the inverter is a modified sine wave type, but was not able to confirm that with Ford.

Comment: The 400W inverter is a very cheap modified sine-wave type. They don't even have  filtering circuitry. The way it outputs might make things such as a battery charger go over-current easily. Look at the sine wave here : https://www.thedieselstop.com/threads/what-i-learned-about-the-spiffy-new-400-watt-inverter.619330/

Comment: Sorry, a little clarification here. The inverter on the SuperDuty has a yellow indicator light. The light is on solid when in use, and flashes when a fault has been detected. The inverter then stops sending power to the outlet until the charger is unplugged. I'm just trying to see if anyone would have an explanation for why the inverter fault light would start flashing when the device being plugged in uses far less power than the maximim rating for the inverter. The charger works fine from a standard wall outlet, and a second SupeDuty inverter was tested and the same flashing light resulted.

Comment: I suggest you get a charger that's intended to run from a 12V vehicle supply directly. I have [one of these](https://www.homedepot.com/p/RYOBI-18-Volt-ONE-In-Vehicle-Dual-Chemistry-Charger-for-use-with-12V-DC-Outlet-P131/100342149) for my tools - I'd be surprised if Milwaukee doesn't have something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.thedieselstop.com/threads/what-i-learned-about-the-spiffy-new-400-watt-inverter.619330/

> The stock inverter is a bit of a joke. Won't power my laptop or my dewalt batter chargers.

The stock 400W inverter of the Ford uses a modified sine wave...or rather...a square wave that looks like something called a sine wave.

[image]

Many chargers use the line voltage to regulate and with a sine-wave like this there's a lot that can happen. The harmonics this kind of square wave can create are immense. Effectively, the charger is tuned for 50 or 60hz. This kind of subpar inverter will mismatch the frequency in many charger circuits. (ex. 150hz instead of 60hz) **This mismatch can create over-current saturation in the transformer of the charger**, or in the regulation, thus pulling more than 4A on the line. (Fuses for your type of charger are usually 4-5A from my experience.) The bottom line is that usually the charger will draw too much current, so the over-current protection will trip on the Inverter.

If there's a better way of explaining then please do say. I'm just saying what I think is happening. All open for a true answer if this isn't.

Given 400W is barely enough for most tools, I suggest just upgrading it to something more powerful, with a true sine wave if possible.

Comment: Thank you. That's the explanation I was looking for.

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted?